# Get the value from the mat-input in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-input

As im new to the angular. I just want to get the value from the mat-input
I need to get the value from the angular mat-input.
Can someone help me to do this.
Thanks in advance

```
<div fxLayoutAlign= "center center" fxFlexFill class="main-div">
<mat-card fxFlex= "20">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" c>Bonbloc Login</mat-toolbar>
    <form fxLayoutAlign="stretch" fxLayout = "column" class="login-form">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput required [(ngModel)] = "email" placeholder="email Id">
          <mat-hint align="end">Min 5 characters</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput required [(ngModel)] = "password" type="password" placeholder="password">
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click) = "login()">Login</button>
        <h1>Hi {{email}} {{password}}</h1>
      </form>
</mat-card>
```

```
login() {
console.log(this.email, this.password)
};
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 0):

What part of it isn't working exactly? It looks as though it should be fine.

```
<input matInput required [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="email Id">
```

Presumably you have a matching line in the `.ts` declaring an `email` field to bind to:

```
public email: string;
```

Or similar.

`[(ngModel)]` Is a two-way binding, meaning whatever you set `email` to programmatically will be put into the text box, and whatever the user puts into the text box will set `email`'s value.

Your `login()` method should be able to see this...

```
public login(): void {
  console.log('Entered email:', this.email);
}
```

Edit: Example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtybqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts) showing the basic binding working. Not using `matInput`, but that won't change the functionality.

Comment: If i need to get the input from the input field itself. and i dont need to put value into the text box means what should i do..???

Comment: I have pasted the login code above. but it doesn't work

Comment: I've added a StackBlitz showing the basic mechanism that you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input matInput required [(ngModel)]="email" [value]="email" placeholder="your email" (change)="valuechange($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
private email : string = '';

  valuechange() {
    console.log(this.email);
  }
```

ng-model directive binds the value of HTML controls like input, select, text-area to a variable created in ts file. so it can be acted as two way binding

Answer (score 0):

Use the name also Something like

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <form>
       <mat-label>Insert Anything</mat-label>
       <input type="text"  matInput [(ngModel)] ="oName" name="oName" >
       <mat-hint>Serie</mat-hint>
    </form>
</mat-form-field>
```